# jquery How to select the 1st cell of each table row

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this:

```
<table id="myTable">
   <tr><td>1sta</td><td>2nd</td></tr>
   <tr><td>1stb</td><td>2nd</td></tr>
   <tr><td>1stc</td><td>2nd</td></tr>
   <tr><td>1std</td><td>2nd</td></tr>
</table>
```

Using jQuery
How do I select the 1st `<td>` element in each row of "myTable"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `first-child` selector grabs each `td` that is the first child of its parent (the `tr` in this case).

```
$('#myTable td:first-child');
```

http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I'll mark this as the correct answer when it lets me.

Comment: This will break for if there's a nested table won't it?

Comment: @blesh - Not if the OP wants to select the first `td` elements in the nested table too. There wasn't any nested table in the question. It will also break if the OP changes the ID of the table.

Comment: And if immediate children are of concern `$('#myTable > tr > td:first-child');` would specify that relationship..

Comment: @Dan Herberden - That's actually a little tricky since some (but not all) browsers automatically insert a `tbody` between the `table` and the `tr` elements, so the selector would break in some cases. Getting rid of the first `>` would bring you back to the original issue. I think you would ultimately have to put an ID on the inner table, and use a `:not()` selector to make sure the `td` doesn't descend from that.

Answer (score 2):

Use this selector `'#myTable td:first-child'`.

That will select the first `td` for **every** `tr`.  Avoid the temptation to use `:first` instead of `:first-child`.  `:first` will only select a single element.  In this case it would be the first cell of the first row.

http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/